# Executable created with pyinstaller can't find DLLs on users' Windows machines

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have successfully created a program and used Pyinstaller to generate an exe file.

It runs in all three of my Windows 10 computers. However some other people have tried it and some can run it, some get the error *"Fatal Error detected: Failed to Execute Script main"* and, more recently, someone said he instead got the error *"error loading python dll"*.

This is really disheartening because I don't have the errors and therefore I don't know how to possibly correct them myself.

--

**Update:**

I followed the advice of using a VM.
I got the *"Fatal Error detected: Failed to Execute Script main"* which is good. Now I can try to solve it.

Then I and analyzed the file with Git Bash. I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "MN_MIDI.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\rtmidi\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

So the problem seems to lie in the *Main>MN_MIDI>rtmidi* module

Since I'm a Python newbie, even after researching for the last hours how to solve this I'm still not sure how.

At the moment I believe that if I could find a rtmidi dll in the Python37 folder, and copy it into the folder generated by Pyinstaller, that would solve my problem, but unfortunately (1) I'm not sure if I'm correct thinking that and (2) there are no rtmidi dlls.
Perhaps this is completely wrong and there is a better way to solve this module error?

Comment: Could be a silly question, but did you distribute the `build` folder or the `dist` folder (you should be doing the latter)? It could be the program can't locate some external resources it's looking for (like `Background01.png`) and causes the program to crash, resulting in the `Fatal Error`.

Comment: Maybe try your exe in a fresh windows VM so you can isolate the dependencies causing problems?  "Works for me" nearly always indicates your system is richer than the others.

Comment: Fatal Error detected: Failed to Execute Script main is most likely because they other people don't have all of the files in the same place as you or dont have them at all. The python dll one looks likes the installation itself is flawed, though I wouldn't know because I don't use windows.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I recommend editing the question to include a better title for this problem. I would suggest something along the lines of, "Unable to load python dll file on users' Windows machine"

Comment: Also depending on what modules are loaded, other external dependencies might not be included as part of the `dist` package.  e.g. for `selenium` you would need to also have the drivers installed besides just your compiled exe.